# How to use swiper 11.0.5 element with Angular 17

Tags: angular, swiper.js, angular17

In angular 17 everything is standalone component and there is no app.module.ts file. So, then where do we put this code,

```
import {register} from "swiper/element";

register();
```

I am getting this error, since register() is not properly registered,

> ERROR TypeError: this.el.nativeElement.initialize is not a function

Fix this error:

> ERROR TypeError: this.el.nativeElement.initialize is not a function

Comment: Have you tried to register it inside main.ts ?

Comment: Yes, I tried in two ways of declaring in main.ts but still I am getting the error message in terminal,
Approach 1:
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .then((module) => {
    register();
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

Approach 2: 
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

import {register} from "swiper/element";

register();

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working using `swiper-elements` but its not a perfect solution, its a bit of an hack solution, I use [`CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`](https://angular.io/api/core/CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA) to get rid of the angular errors, for element is not found, then it started working fine!

swiper wrapper html

```
<swiper-container
  slides-per-view="1"
  speed="500"
  loop="true"
  css-mode="true"
  navigation="true"
  pagination="true"
  scrollbar="true"
>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400" /></swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>
```

swiper wrapper ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-swiper',
  standalone: true,
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  templateUrl: './swiper.component.html',
})
export class SwiperComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-u7jxiq)

[ngFor example stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-y4t2d4)

Comment: Thanks, Naren for sharing. But, I want to inject styles beyond shadow dom. For, that we need to do register() and initialize the native element.

Comment: @VijaiS you can set `ViewEncapsulation.None` and define the CSS whatever is needed, this will get applied, you also can override using `!important`!

Comment: Hi Naren,
How do you achieve this here.
<swiper-container swiperElement [config]="config" init="false">
  <swiper-slide *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3]">
    Slide {{i}}
  </swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>

Comment: @VijaiS [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-y4t2d4) here

Comment: Thanks Naren, this helps. 
I have another question related to swiper. If you have time, can you check on that.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77786595/how-to-make-only-bootstrap-dropdown-overflow-y-visible-in-swiper-element-11-0-5