# In Angular 17 standalone mode, how can I make Bootstrap dropdown visible outside of a Swiper element using Swiper version 11.0.5

Tags: angular, swiper.js, angular17

Here in the below swiper code, How do I make bootstrap dropdown to visible outside of swiper container. I don't want to auto height the swiper container. I want my container to have fixed height and only the dropdown overflow should visible. I tried setting overflow-y: visible in the swiper container it doesn't workout. Can someone help me out.

here is the stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-pmtemc?file=src%2Fswiper%2Fswiper.component.html)

```
Html:
    <swiper-container
  appSwiper
  [config]="swiperConfig"
  style="background: black;color: white;height: 100px;"
>
  <swiper-slide>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button
        class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
        type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
        aria-expanded="false"
      >
        Dropdown button
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide *ngFor="let item of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]"
    >Slide {{ item }}</swiper-slide
  >
</swiper-container>
```

ts:

```
import { Component, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { SwiperDirective } from '../swiper.directive';
import { SwiperOptions } from 'swiper/types';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-swiper',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [SwiperDirective, CommonModule, SwiperDirective],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  templateUrl: './swiper.component.html',
  styleUrl: './swiper.component.scss',
})
export class SwiperComponent {
  swiperConfig: SwiperOptions = {
    spaceBetween: 10,
    navigation: true,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
  };
}
```

Directive:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { SwiperContainer } from 'swiper/element';
import { SwiperOptions } from 'swiper/types';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSwiper]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class SwiperDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() config?: SwiperOptions;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef<SwiperContainer>) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    Object.assign(this.el.nativeElement, this.config);
    this.el.nativeElement.initialize();
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
import { SwiperComponent } from './swiper/swiper.component';
register();
```

[image]

Updated:
updated code [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ff5u6c?file=src%2Fswiper%2Fswiper.component.html)

When setting the overflow visible property on the shadow dom it increases the width of viewport and added an horizontal scroll bar which makes hidden slides visible but it should not work like that.

Expected behavior: Only dropdown should have option to expand without adding horizontal scroll bar.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had kept 'hello' as id attribute in

```
<swiper-container
  appSwiper
  id="hello"
  [config]="swiperConfig"
  style="background: black;color: white;height: 100px;"
>
```

and for TS file changes, I did as below,

```
  el: HTMLDivElement | undefined | null;

  constructor(private rend: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    const sr = document.querySelector('#hello')?.shadowRoot;
    this.el = sr?.querySelector('div');
    this.rend.setStyle(this.el, 'overflow', 'visible');
  }
```

Basically, all I did was changing the overflow property of shadow-root's div element overflow property to 'visible'

Hope it helps !

Comment: This triggers another scroll bar issue.

Comment: ok. Give me link to verify. And Please explain in detail.

Comment: Link is here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ff5u6c?file=src%2Fswiper%2Fswiper.component.html

Comment: For <swiper-container>, I had added few attributes as below,

  slides-per-view="1"
  loop="true"
  css-mode="true"

Comment: It doesn't work. Do you have working stackblitz?

Comment: Please verify - https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xzvpwo?file=src%2Fswiper%2Fswiper.component.html

Comment: @VijaiS Did it work?, Can you reply back ?