# Swiper in Angular 17

Tags: angular, ngx-swiper-wrapper

I'm diving into Angular 17 for a project and trying to integrate Swiper for a slick carousel feature. I've been scratching my head trying to get it to work but hitting a few roadblocks.

Has anyone here successfully implemented Swiper in Angular 17? I'm looking for some working example or a guide that's up to date with Angular 17's nuances.

I've tried to play with the swiper documentation to get it to function properly but to no avail.

Any help or pointers would be super appreciated!

Comment: I did. for some reason it did not work aswell and needed to be tweaked with CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA based on the post @https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77785497/how-to-use-swiper-11-0-5-element-with-angular-17 . but i wasn't able to make it work aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Component,
  ContentChild,
  ElementRef,
  Input,
  effect,
} from '@angular/core';
import { SwiperContainer } from 'swiper/element/bundle';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-swiper',
  templateUrl: './swiper.component.html',
  styleUrl: './swiper.component.css',
  standalone: true,
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class SwiperComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() swiperContainerId = '';
  index = 0;
  slidePerView = 1;

  @ContentChild('swiper') swiperRef!: ElementRef<SwiperContainer>;
  initialized = false;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const shadowRoot = document
        .getElementById(this.swiperContainerId)
        ?.getElementsByClassName('swiper')[0]?.shadowRoot
        ?.firstChild as HTMLElement;
      shadowRoot.style.paddingBottom = '35px';
    }, 300);
  }

  changeSlide(prevOrNext: number): void {
    if (prevOrNext === -1) {
      this.swiperRef.nativeElement.swiper.slidePrev();
    } else {
      this.swiperRef.nativeElement.swiper.slideNext();
    }
  }
}
```

The following example works in angular 17.1 and swiper 11.0.5. It works with content projection. You can improve this code and let me know below this post and I will appreciate it.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-x8wczt?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fswiper%2Fswiper.component.ts,package.json&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: The [Swiper Element setup documentation](https://swiperjs.com/element#install--register-from-npm) specifically says not to call `register()` more than once. It can be moved from `SwiperComponent` to your `main.ts` file (before the call to `bootstrapApplication()`).

Comment: i got it to work with something that is close to yours, however i'm `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'remove') - at destroyModule` . can you tell me what did i miss ? heres what i did https://www.coderstool.com/cs/Pkd9AW

Comment: where is destroy module? where is remove?
can you share a real example in stackblitz?

Comment: i was not able to replicate my environment as needed to demonstrate the issue. However i did something that is close that should give an idea about what im trying to achieve in a way or another https://stackblitz-starters-c7vwgq.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 4):

The `ngx-swiper-wrapper` package you tagged [was deprecated](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-swiper-wrapper?tab=readme-ov-file#eol-notice) because Swiper started supporting Angular directly. Looks like [Swiper for Angular](https://swiperjs.com/angular) was removed in v9 and they recommend using [Swiper Element](https://swiperjs.com/element) (which appears to be just a Web Components version of the library) instead.

Following the installation instructions in the Swiper Element documentation, I managed to get a working Angular 17 [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vactfn?file=src%2Fapp.component.ts). I followed these steps:

1. `npm install swiper`.
2. Add `import { register as registerSwiperElements } from 'swiper/element/bundle';` to your `main.ts` file and call `registerSwiperElements()` before the call to `bootstrapApplication()` so that the custom elements are registered before the application tries to use them.

> I'm assuming a standalone app here. If you're using an `NgModule` to bootstrap, place the call for `registerSwiperElements()` before
> the call to `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule()`.
>
> I think this is the part you're missing. The custom elements have to be registered with JavaScript (see [CustomElementRegistry.define()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define) for details about this) before they're available to use. This should ideally be done as soon as possible so they're available when the application starts rendering.

3. Add `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to the definition of any component(s)
   that use(s) the Swiper Element components.

My `main.ts` ended up looking like this:

```js
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { register as registerSwiperElements } from 'swiper/element/bundle';
import { App } from './app.component';

// Register Swiper custom elements. We do this
// before bootstrapping the Angular application
// so that they're available before any part of
// our application tries rendering them.
registerSwiperElements();

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

And my `app.component.ts` ended up looking like this:

```js
import { Component, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <p>Swipe to change slides</p>
    <swiper-container loop="true">
      <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
      <swiper-slide>Slide 4</swiper-slide>
    </swiper-container>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
    swiper-slide {
      height: 400px;
    }
    swiper-slide:nth-of-type(1) {
      background-color: red;
    }
    swiper-slide:nth-of-type(2) {
      background-color: green;
    }
    swiper-slide:nth-of-type(3) {
      background-color: blue;
      color: white;
    }
    swiper-slide:nth-of-type(4) {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  `,
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class App {}
```

The swiper works as expected. Here it is part of the way through a transition from slide 1 to slide 2:

[image: A screenshot of the output of the linked StackBlitz showing a carousel transitioning between a red slide and a green slide]